# Program stops working after building it and inputting values - string related issue

Tags: c++, string, crash

Ok, so here's the deal. I was writing this program that takes a lower-case vowel from a user-inputted string and adds the upper-case vowel right next to it (please note I am new to coding, like, very new, but I dig it loads and I wanna get the hang of it). What happens with this is that I build the program and run it, I input a string in the console and then the whole thing just crashes. I don't see why that is. Can anybody help out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[21], *p="aeiou", *aux;
    int i;
    cin.get(s,21);
    for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        if (strchr(p, s[i])!=0)
        {
            strcpy(aux, s+i);
            strcpy(s+i+1, aux);
            s[i+1]=s[i+1]-32;
        }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate space for `aux` - in your code it's a pointer which is not pointing to a defined place.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to do. But I can see that you have not allocated memory for "aux" but copying data. Instead of "char *aux" write "char aux[21]". This may fix the crash.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, you guys :)

Comment: Just to further explain what I was doing, imagine that if I inputted "carrot", my program would've printed "caArroOt". Many thanks, it totally slipped my mind